# position: absolute with unknown top

Tags: html, css-position

I have some markup:

```
<div class="header">Unknown content size</div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Both blocks should have constant height: header.height + main.height = 100% windows height.
If header has fixed height there is no problem: position absolute for main with top: header.height and bottom: 0. 
But header may be with different amount of content.

I need support for IE7+, so flexbox layout is not a answer.
Table layout is very good for this problem, but i need absolute positioned "main" block.

May be it's impossible without JS

Like that:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a rough diagram of what you're trying to do? I don't really understand the question in its current state.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible without flex, table display or js.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understand your question. But I can guess and made it **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/WVSz4/1/)** 
Please let me know, this is what you looking for? if no sorry :)

**html**

```
<div id="header">
    <p>Header</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<div id="main">Content</div>
```

**css**

```
#header {
    background:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
#main {
background:green;
    color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**js**

```
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var headHeight = $("#header").height();

$("#main").height(winHeight-headHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably need a javascript file.

I have done some work. it will work for you.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="header"><h2>Header content will be here</h2></div>
    <div class="main"><h1>Main content will be here</h1></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
body {position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%}
div.header {position:fixed;background:#FC0;top:0;z-index:2;width:100%;}
div.main {background:#CCC;position:relative;}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
      //detect the width on page load
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var main_height = $(window).height();
        var header_height = $(".header").height();
        $(".main").height(main_height - header_height).css('padding-top', header_height);
      });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

You can check the demo [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mmanish27/9XbN5/)

Comment: Yeah, its not a problem with some JS, but i cant use script. Its can be done with additional table wrapper, so main block absolute positioned in table cell. Only its not work in IE9+ and i have some troubles with Opera12 with this table.